# Subscribe to Event Channel on Java application - Cumulocity

Tags: events, subscription, complex-event-processing, cumulocity

I'm trying to subscribe to the Event Channel in a Java Application.
I'm trying to instantiate a new Subscriber following the example found here.

[How the java client in cumulocity listens to events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830883/how-the-java-client-in-cumulocity-listens-to-events)

I'm interested in particular at the events happening on a device so what I'm doing is subscribe to the channel "/events/123" where 123 is the device id.

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
{
   String uRl = "urlOfMyCumulocityIstance"; 
   CumulocityCredentials rC = new CumulocityCredentials("username","password");
   PlatformParameters parameters = new PlatformParameters(uRl,rC,new ClientConfiguration());
   CepCustomNotificationsSubscriber t = new CepCustomNotificationsSubscriber(parameters);
   System.out.println(t.toString() + " - " + t.CEP_CUSTOM_NOTIFICATIONS_URL.toString()); // It prints an integer number corresponding to the subscriber t.

   t.subscribe("/events/123", new SubscriptionListener<String, Object>() {

    public void onError(Subscription arg0, Throwable arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(arg1.getMessage());

    }

    public void onNotification(Subscription arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(arg1);

    }

   });

}
```

Nevertheless I'm not getting any of the events sent to the device.

To sum up, what I'd like to do is what in Apama you do by typing

```
monitor.subscribe(Event.CHANNEL)
on all Event(source=123) as e 
{
   // do something
}
```

Any idea about it?
Thank in advance